# Will iOS 8 require the use of Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

As you may know apple released iOS 8 and swift. So for the apps that I will create this summer (before the public release of iOS 8), will they need to be written in objective-c or swift? If I make these apps and they get accepted during the summer using objective-c will I need to upgrade my apps to support iOS 8 in the fall?

And finally once iOS 8 is out, will we be forced to only use swift, or can we still create apps strictly off objective-c?

Comment: As far as I know Apple will not enforce usage of any programming language for acceptance on the store.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C isn't going anywhere (yet). And you don't have to rerelease your apps for every new version of iOS, unless the new version breaks something.

You can't use beta versions of Xcode to submit to the App Store, though, so if you do plan to submit before 8 comes out, make sure your project is compatible with Xcode 5 (which means no Swift).

Comment: So i can still have .m and .h objective-c files instead of .swift when iOS 8 comes out? Thanks

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It's not a replacement. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a firm stand from apple on how long will objective c be supported.

But objective c can be mixed and matched with Swift and most of the UIKit and AppKit is written in Objective c means Objc will be supported in the near future.  I can't see apple rewrite the entire appkit and uikit in swift and deprecate Objc in the next 2 years.

Beyond that is anyone's guess and also things might get effy if apple start to introduce new api only for swift.

I think you are fine with Objc for the next a few years, right now i don't think you can release app written with swift in app store (let me know if i'm wrong).